Very ample line bundle isomorphic to $F^* H$, where $H$ is the hyperplane bundle
Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold, $L \to M$ a very ample line bundle and $F : M \to \Bbb {CP}^n$ the associated embedding into $\Bbb{CP}^n$. I'm trying to show that $L \cong F^*H$, where $H \to \Bbb{CP}^n$ is the hyperplane bundle i.e. the dual of the tautological line bundle.
Since $M$ is compact the space $H^0(M,L)$ is finite-dimensional and thus we can pick a basis $s_0,\dots,s_n$ for $H^0(M,L)$ and then the embedding $F$ is given by $$F(p)=[s_0(p):\dots:s_n(p)].$$
Now I don't know if I lack some of the theory, but one way to show that two bundles are isomorphic would be to show that they have the same transition maps. We know the transition maps for $F^*H$, but we do not know them for $L$ so that might not be an approach we can take here.
What I tried to do was to consider the transition functions for $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ and use them to get the transition maps
$$
g_{\alpha\beta} = \frac{z_\beta}{z_\alpha}
$$
for $H$ and thus the pullback would have transition maps
$$
g_{\alpha\beta} \circ F = \frac{s_\beta}{s_\alpha}.
$$
One would still need to show that these are the transition maps for $L$, but I don't think we can do that.
Exhibiting also a bundle map $L \to F^*H$ that would end up being an isomorphism seems rather difficult. Is there some theorem we can use here?

You're almost there... Your description above basically constructs a homomorphism $L \to F^*H$.
Write $z_k$ for the homogenous coordinates on $\mathbb P^n$. Then, on the open set $U_k=D(s_k)$ (the set $\{p\in M\mid s_k(p) \not=0\}$, take $$s\mapsto \Big({s\over s_k}\Big) \cdot F^*z_k,$$
where $s/s_k$ denotes the element of $\Gamma( U_k, \cal O)$ for which
$$s=\Big({s\over s_k}\Big) \cdot s_k$$ holds on $U_k$. (I would probably write $z_k$ for $F^*z_k$.)
Of course, you need to verify that the homomorphism is well-defined ( and that is an isomorphism!).
From the transition function point of view, we are using
$${s_l\over s_k} = F^{*}\Big({z_l\over z_k}\Big),$$
as in the preceding notation.

Gee, I had wanted to make this 'community,' (since 'my' answer is standard - if correct!) but I don't see the option - has this possibility disappeared?
